# How to load data by sql Lite

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'd like to use Sql Lite to load the to-do list into the table calendar. I want to load the data using Future Builder. But this error keeps popping up. Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
    ════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](Instance of 'DateTime')

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _TodoListState._showAddDialog.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>     (package:take_a_note_project/pomodoro/todoList/todoList.dart:100:30)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1233:30)
#3      _TodoListState._showAddDialog.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>     (package:take_a_note_project/pomodoro/todoList/todoList.dart:92:17)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#114ce
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(306.4, 463.6)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(22.4, 15.6)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

this is todoList Code. A code that uses a calendar to write a to-do list on that date.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
    import './dateBaseHelper.dart';
    
    class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _TodoListState createState() => _TodoListState();
    }
    
    class _TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
    
      CalendarController _controller;
      Map<DateTime, dynamic> _events; 
      TextEditingController _eventController; 
      List<dynamic> _selectedEvents;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _controller = CalendarController();
        _eventController = TextEditingController();
        _selectedEvents = [];
      }
    
      Future<void> loadData() async{
        _events = await todos();
      } // I created a loadData function separately because it is not possible to specify asyc for initState.
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _TableCalendar(),
                      ... _selectedEvents.map((todoItem) => Card(
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        child:  ListTile(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                          title: Text(todoItem.todo),
                        ),
                      )),
                    ],
                  )
              )
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: _showAddDialog,
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget _TableCalendar(){
        return TableCalendar( // Calendar Style
          events: _events,
          calendarStyle: CalendarStyle( // Calendar Style
            todayColor: Colors.orange,
          ),
          calendarController: _controller,
          onDaySelected: (date, events) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedEvents = events;
            });
          },
        );
      }
    
      _showAddDialog(){
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              content: TextField(
                controller: _eventController,
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Save"),
                  onPressed: (){ // Code for storing data.
                    if(_eventController.text.isEmpty) return;
                    setState(() {
                      TodoItem todoItem = TodoItem(
                        id: 0,
                        todo: _eventController.text,
                        isDone: false,
                        time: _controller.selectedDay,
                      );
    
                      if (_events[_controller.selectedDay] != null){
                        _events[_controller.selectedDay].add(todoItem);
                      }else {
                        _events[_controller.selectedDay] = [todoItem];
                      }
                      _eventController.clear();
                      insertTodo(todoItem);
                      _eventController.clear();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

this is data base helper code

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:path/path.dart';
    import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
    import 'package:take_a_note_project/main.dart';
    
    class TodoItem {
      int id;
      String todo;
      bool isDone;
      DateTime time;
    
      TodoItem({
        this.id,
        this.todo,
        this.isDone,
        this.time
      });
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        return {
          'id': id,
          'todo': todo,
          'isDone': isDone,
          'time': time
        };
      }
    }
    
    void main() async {
      database = openDatabase ( // to make dataBase Table
    
        join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'todo_database.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
          return db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE dogs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, todo TEXT, isDone BOOLEAN)",
          );
        },
    
        version: 1,
      );
    
    }
    
      Future<void> insertTodo(TodoItem todoItem) async {
    
        final Database db = await database;
    
    
        await db.insert(
          'todos',
          todoItem.toMap(),
          conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
        );
      }
    
      Future<Map<DateTime, dynamic>> todos() async {
    
        final Database db = await database;
    
        final List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = await db.query('todos');
        Map<DateTime, dynamic> eventResult = {};
    
        items.forEach((item) {
          eventResult[item['time']] = TodoItem(
            id: item['id'],
            todo: item['todo'],
            isDone: item['isDone'],
            time: item['time'],
          );
        });
        return eventResult;
      }
    
      Future<void> updateTodo(TodoItem todoItem) async {
    
        final db = await database;
    
        await db.update(
          'todos',
          todoItem.toMap(),
          where: "id = ?",
    
          whereArgs: [todoItem.id],
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> deleteTodos(int id) async {
        final db = await database;
    
    
        await db.delete(
          'todos',
          where: "id = ?",
          whereArgs: [id],
        );
      }
```

I uploaded the code to the GitHub.
[todoList code](https://github.com/Yummy-sk/Take-a-note/tree/master/lib/pomodoro/todoList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you can do, is not specify a return type for your load todos method, then call the signature inside initState.

```
_loadData() async { 
_events = await todos(); 
}

initState() {
 _loadData();
}
```

That error is saying you are trying to access a null DateTime instance.   Check to make sure all data is properly being loaded into your insertTodo method properly.